# Writing a TTL decorator in Python

Tags: python, decorator, ttl

I'm trying to write a TTL decorator in python.
Basically I give it raise an exception if the function doesn't
answer in the selected time.

You can find the thead2 snippets on http://sebulba.wikispaces.com/recipe+thread2

```
from thread2 import Thread

"""  A TTL decorator. """
class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, q, f, args, kvargs):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.q = q
        self.f = f
        self.args = args
        self.kvargs = kvargs

    def run(self,):
        try:
            res = (True, self.f(*self.args, **self.kvargs))
            self.q.put(res)
        except Exception, e:
            self.q.put((False, e))

class Referee(Thread):
    def __init__(self,q, ttl,exception_factory):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.exception_factory=exception_factory    
        self.q=q
        self.ttl=ttl

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.ttl)
        res = (False, self.exception_factory())
        self.q.put(res)

def raise_if_too_long(ttl, exception_factory=lambda :RuntimeError("Timeout")):
    def raise_if_too_long_aux(f):
        def ritl(*args,**kvargs):
            q = Queue.Queue(2)

            referee = Referee(q, ttl, exception_factory)
            worker = Worker(q,f,args,kvargs)

            worker.start()
            referee.start()

            (valid, res)= q.get(1)

            q.task_done()

            referee.terminate()
            worker.terminate()

            if valid:
                return res
            else:
                raise res

        return ritl

    return raise_if_too_long_aux
```

However, I get some pretty bad result.
It seems like sometimes the function is returning alright yet
the decorator doesn't return until the TTL is reached and the error 
raises.

Do you see something wrong in this code?
Is there a common way/library to write function with a TTL in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code provided is a bit tough to follow -- how is it going to raise an exception in the right place at the right time in the right thread?

**Consider this rough flow:**

Decorator function called with target function. Return a function which:

2. Starts thread, calling target function
3. Joins to thread using thread.join([timeout])
4. If you get a timeout, raise an exception, and ignore the result of the thread.
5. If you don't get a timeout, capture the result of the thread and return it.

(You would need to devise a way to capture the output of the thread...)

See http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html for info on the threading timeout...

*(Or just start using [erlang](http://www.erlang.org) **`:)`***

Comment: Thank you it really helped. I didn't know thread.join(timeout).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function's execution to be terminated after the timeout has been exceeded, you might want to try code that has that capability. To use the module, all that needs to be done is for your function to be called as an argument to `add_timeout`, and the returned value can run. Once called, the object's `ready` property can be polled, and anything returned can be accessed via the `value` property. The code's documentation should provide an explanation for the rest of the available API.

**[code redacted for length]** See [timeout.py](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577045/) for source.

---

**Addendum:**

There is another way of looking at the problem. Instead of decorating a function to have a time-to-live, you could submit the function and its arguments to an execution engine that can enforce a timeout on how long it can run for. My original answer up above was a solution to this problem about eight years ago. After further study on the subject, may I recommend the following module instead? The module that follows it is used for testing and demonstrating usage of the `asynchronous` module.

**asynchronous.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import abc as _abc
import collections as _collections
import enum as _enum
import math as _math
import multiprocessing as _multiprocessing
import operator as _operator
import queue as _queue
import signal as _signal
import sys as _sys
import time as _time

__all__ = (
    'Executor',
    'get_timeout',
    'set_timeout',
    'submit',
    'map_',
    'shutdown'
)


class _Base(metaclass=_abc.ABCMeta):
    __slots__ = (
        '__timeout',
    )

    @_abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = _math.inf if timeout is None else timeout

    def get_timeout(self):
        return self.__timeout

    def set_timeout(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, (float, int)):
            raise TypeError('value must be of type float or int')
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError('value must be greater than zero')
        self.__timeout = value

    timeout = property(get_timeout, set_timeout)


def _run_and_catch(fn, args, kwargs):
    # noinspection PyPep8,PyBroadException
    try:
        return False, fn(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        return True, _sys.exc_info()[1]


def _run(fn, args, kwargs, queue):
    queue.put_nowait(_run_and_catch(fn, args, kwargs))


class _State(_enum.IntEnum):
    PENDING = _enum.auto()
    RUNNING = _enum.auto()
    CANCELLED = _enum.auto()
    FINISHED = _enum.auto()
    ERROR = _enum.auto()


def _run_and_catch_loop(iterable, *args, **kwargs):
    exception = None
    for fn in iterable:
        error, value = _run_and_catch(fn, args, kwargs)
        if error:
            exception = value
    if exception:
        raise exception


class _Future(_Base):
    __slots__ = (
        '__queue',
        '__process',
        '__start_time',
        '__callbacks',
        '__result'
    )

    def __init__(self, timeout, fn, args, kwargs):
        super().__init__(timeout)
        self.__queue = _multiprocessing.Queue(1)
        self.__process = _multiprocessing.Process(
            target=_run,
            args=(fn, args, kwargs, self.__queue),
            daemon=True
        )
        self.__start_time = _math.inf
        self.__callbacks = _collections.deque()
        self.__result = True, TimeoutError()

    @property
    def __state(self):
        pid, exitcode = self.__process.pid, self.__process.exitcode
        return (_State.PENDING if pid is None else
                _State.RUNNING if exitcode is None else
                _State.CANCELLED if exitcode == -_signal.SIGTERM else
                _State.FINISHED if exitcode == 0 else
                _State.ERROR)

    def __repr__(self):
        root = f'{type(self).__name__} at {id(self)} state={self.__state.name}'
        if self.__state < _State.CANCELLED:
            return f'<{root}>'
        error, value = self.__result
        suffix = f'{"raised" if error else "returned"} {type(value).__name__}'
        return f'<{root} {suffix}>'

    def __consume_callbacks(self):
        while self.__callbacks:
            yield self.__callbacks.popleft()

    def __invoke_callbacks(self):
        self.__process.join()
        _run_and_catch_loop(self.__consume_callbacks(), self)

    def cancel(self):
        self.__process.terminate()
        self.__invoke_callbacks()

    def __auto_cancel(self):
        elapsed_time = _time.perf_counter() - self.__start_time
        if elapsed_time > self.timeout:
            self.cancel()
        return elapsed_time

    def cancelled(self):
        self.__auto_cancel()
        return self.__state is _State.CANCELLED

    def running(self):
        self.__auto_cancel()
        return self.__state is _State.RUNNING

    def done(self):
        self.__auto_cancel()
        return self.__state > _State.RUNNING

    def __handle_result(self, error, value):
        self.__result = error, value
        self.__invoke_callbacks()

    def __ensure_termination(self):
        elapsed_time = self.__auto_cancel()
        if not self.__queue.empty():
            self.__handle_result(*self.__queue.get_nowait())
        elif self.__state < _State.CANCELLED:
            remaining_time = self.timeout - elapsed_time
            if remaining_time == _math.inf:
                remaining_time = None
            try:
                result = self.__queue.get(True, remaining_time)
            except _queue.Empty:
                self.cancel()
            else:
                self.__handle_result(*result)

    def result(self):
        self.__ensure_termination()
        error, value = self.__result
        if error:
            raise value
        return value

    def exception(self):
        self.__ensure_termination()
        error, value = self.__result
        if error:
            return value

    def add_done_callback(self, fn):
        if self.done():
            fn(self)
        else:
            self.__callbacks.append(fn)

    def _set_running_or_notify_cancel(self):
        if self.__state is _State.PENDING:
            self.__process.start()
            self.__start_time = _time.perf_counter()
        else:
            self.cancel()


class Executor(_Base):
    __slots__ = (
        '__futures',
    )

    def __init__(self, timeout=None):
        super().__init__(timeout)
        self.__futures = set()

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        future = _Future(self.timeout, fn, args, kwargs)
        self.__futures.add(future)
        future.add_done_callback(self.__futures.remove)
        # noinspection PyProtectedMember
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        return future

    @staticmethod
    def __cancel_futures(iterable):
        _run_and_catch_loop(map(_operator.attrgetter('cancel'), iterable))

    def map(self, fn, *iterables):
        futures = tuple(self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables))

        def result_iterator():
            future_iterator = iter(futures)
            try:
                for future in future_iterator:
                    yield future.result()
            finally:
                self.__cancel_futures(future_iterator)

        return result_iterator()

    def shutdown(self):
        self.__cancel_futures(frozenset(self.__futures))

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.shutdown()
        return False


_executor = Executor()
get_timeout = _executor.get_timeout
set_timeout = _executor.set_timeout
submit = _executor.submit
map_ = _executor.map
shutdown = _executor.shutdown
del _executor
```

**test_asynchronous.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import _thread
import atexit
import functools
import inspect
import io
import math
import operator
import os
import sys
import time
import unittest

import asynchronous


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class TestConstructor:
    def instantiate(self, *args):
        parameters = len(inspect.signature(self.CLASS).parameters)
        return self.CLASS(*args[:parameters])

    def test_valid_timeout(self):
        instance = self.instantiate(None, print, (), {})
        self.assertEqual(instance.get_timeout(), math.inf)
        instance = self.instantiate(1, print, (), {})
        self.assertEqual(instance.get_timeout(), 1)
        float_timeout = (math.e ** (1j * math.pi) + 1).imag
        self.assertIsInstance(float_timeout, float)
        instance = self.instantiate(float_timeout, print, (), {})
        self.assertEqual(instance.get_timeout(), float_timeout)

    def test_error_timeout(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.instantiate, '60', print, (), {})
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.instantiate, 0, print, (), {})
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.instantiate, -1, print, (), {})


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class TestTimeout(TestConstructor):
    def test_valid_property(self):
        instance = self.instantiate(None, None, None, None)
        instance.timeout = 1
        self.assertIsInstance(instance.timeout, int)
        instance.timeout = 1 / 2
        self.assertIsInstance(instance.timeout, float)
        kilo_bit = int.from_bytes(os.urandom(1 << 7), 'big')
        instance.timeout = kilo_bit
        self.assertEqual(instance.timeout, kilo_bit)

    def test_error_property(self):
        instance = self.instantiate(None, None, None, None)
        for exception, value in (
                (TypeError, 'inf'),
                (TypeError, complex(123456789, 0)),
                (ValueError, 0),
                (ValueError, 0.0),
                (ValueError, -1),
                (ValueError, -math.pi)
        ):
            with self.assertRaises(exception):
                instance.timeout = value
            self.assertEqual(instance.timeout, math.inf)


class Timer:
    __timers = {}

    @classmethod
    def start_timer(cls):
        ident, now = _thread.get_ident(), time.perf_counter()
        if now is not cls.__timers.setdefault(ident, now):
            raise KeyError(ident)

    @classmethod
    def stop_timer(cls, expected_time, error=None):
        if error is None:
            error = 1 / 4  # the default is a quarter second
        used = time.perf_counter() - cls.__timers.pop(_thread.get_ident())
        diff = used - expected_time
        return -error <= diff <= +error


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class TestTimer(Timer):
    def stop_timer(self, expected_time, error=None):
        self.assertTrue(super().stop_timer(expected_time, error))


def delay_run(delay, fn, *args, sync=True, **kwargs):
    def wrapper():
        time.sleep(delay)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    if sync:
        return wrapper()
    _thread.start_new_thread(wrapper, ())


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class TestModuleOrInstance(TestTimer):
    @property
    def moi(self):
        return self.MODULE_OR_INSTANCE

    def test_valid_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(math.inf)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), math.inf)
        self.moi.set_timeout(60)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), 60)
        self.moi.set_timeout(0.05)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), 0.05)

    def test_error_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(math.inf)
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.moi.set_timeout, None)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), math.inf)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.moi.set_timeout, 0)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), math.inf)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.moi.set_timeout, -1)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), math.inf)

    def run_submit_check(self):
        self.start_timer()
        future = self.moi.submit(delay_run, 0.5, operator.add, 1, 2)
        self.assertRegex(repr(future), r'^<_Future at \d+ state=RUNNING>$')
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 3)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=FINISHED returned int>$'
        )

    def test_submit_one_second_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1)
        self.run_submit_check()

    def test_submit_no_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(math.inf)
        self.run_submit_check()

    def test_submit_short_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(0.5)
        self.start_timer()
        future = self.moi.submit(delay_run, 1, operator.add, 1, 2)
        self.assertRegex(repr(future), r'^<_Future at \d+ state=RUNNING>$')
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), TimeoutError)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=CANCELLED raised TimeoutError>$'
        )

    def run_map(self, *args):
        return getattr(self.moi, self.NAME_OF_MAP)(delay_run, *args)

    def test_valid_map(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1.5)
        for result in self.run_map(
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [operator.add] * 4,
                [0, 1, 2, 3],
                [3, 2, 1, 0]
        ):
            self.assertEqual(result, 3)

    def test_error_map(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1.5)
        success = 0
        with self.assertRaises(TimeoutError):
            for result in self.run_map(
                    [1, 1, 2, 1],
                    [operator.add] * 4,
                    [0, 1, 2, 3],
                    [3, 2, 1, 0]
            ):
                self.assertEqual(result, 3)
                success += 1
        self.assertEqual(success, 2)

    def run_shutdown_check(self, running, future):
        self.assertRaises(TimeoutError, future.result)
        running.remove(future)

    def run_submit_loop(self, executor):
        running = set()
        done_callback = functools.partial(self.run_shutdown_check, running)
        for _ in range(10):
            future = executor.submit(delay_run, 2, operator.add, 10, 20)
            running.add(future)
            future.add_done_callback(done_callback)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        return running

    def test_valid_shutdown(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1.5)
        running = self.run_submit_loop(self.moi)
        self.moi.shutdown()
        self.assertFalse(running)

    def test_error_shutdown(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1.5)
        running = self.run_submit_loop(self.moi)
        running.pop()
        self.assertRaises(KeyError, self.moi.shutdown)
        self.assertFalse(running)


class TestExecutorAPI(TestTimeout, TestModuleOrInstance, unittest.TestCase):
    CLASS = asynchronous.Executor
    MODULE_OR_INSTANCE = CLASS()
    NAME_OF_MAP = 'map'

    def test_valid_context_manager(self):
        with self.instantiate(1.5) as executor:
            running = self.run_submit_loop(executor)
        self.assertFalse(running)

    def test_error_context_manager(self):
        error = Exception()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as cm:
            with self.instantiate(1.5) as executor:
                running = self.run_submit_loop(executor)
                raise error
        self.assertIs(cm.exception, error)
        self.assertFalse(running)
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
            with self.instantiate(1.5) as executor:
                running = self.run_submit_loop(executor)
                running.pop()
        self.assertFalse(running)


class TestModuleAPI(TestModuleOrInstance, unittest.TestCase):
    MODULE_OR_INSTANCE = asynchronous
    NAME_OF_MAP = 'map_'


def verify_error():
    sys.stderr.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
    for line in sys.stderr:
        if line == 'queue.Full\n':
            break
    else:
        sys.stderr.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
        sys.__stderr__.write(sys.stderr.read())
        sys.__stderr__.flush()


def cause_error(obj):
    sys.stderr = io.StringIO()
    atexit.register(verify_error)
    inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals['queue'].put_nowait(obj)


def return_(obj):
    return obj


# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def throw(exception, *args):
    raise exception


class TestFutureAPI(TestTimer, TestTimeout, unittest.TestCase):
    CLASS = asynchronous._Future

    def test_valid_representation(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertRegex(repr(future), r'^<_Future at \d+ state=PENDING>$')
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertRegex(repr(future), r'^<_Future at \d+ state=RUNNING>$')
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=CANCELLED raised TimeoutError>$'
        )
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=FINISHED raised TimeoutError>$'
        )
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=FINISHED returned NoneType>$'
        )

    def test_error_representation(self):
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, cause_error, (None,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, future.result)
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), TimeoutError)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=ERROR raised TimeoutError>$'
        )
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, cause_error, ((False, 'okay'),), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 'okay')
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=ERROR returned str>$'
        )

    def test_cancel(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertRaises(AttributeError, future.cancel)
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        future.cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.cancelled())
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        checker = set()
        future.add_done_callback(checker.add)
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        future.cancel()
        future.cancel()
        self.assertIs(checker.pop(), future)
        self.assertFalse(checker)

    def test_cancelled(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertFalse(future.cancelled())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertFalse(future.cancelled())
        self.assertIs(future.result(), None)
        self.assertFalse(future.cancelled())
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        future.cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.cancelled())
        future = self.instantiate(0.1, time.sleep, (1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.assertTrue(future.cancelled())

    def test_running(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertFalse(future.running())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.running())
        self.assertIs(future.result(), None)
        self.assertFalse(future.running())
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        future.cancel()
        self.assertFalse(future.running())
        future = self.instantiate(0.1, time.sleep, (1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.assertFalse(future.running())

    def test_done(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertFalse(future.done())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertFalse(future.done())
        self.assertIs(future.result(), None)
        self.assertTrue(future.done())
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (None,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), TypeError)
        self.assertTrue(future.done())

    def test_result_immediate(self):
        data = os.urandom(1 << 20)
        future = self.instantiate(None, return_, (data,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), data)
        test_exception = Exception('test')
        future = self.instantiate(None, throw, (test_exception,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as cm:
            future.result()
        self.assertIsInstance(cm.exception, type(test_exception))
        self.assertEqual(cm.exception.args, test_exception.args)

    def test_result_delay(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 3)
        self.stop_timer(0.1)
        future = self.instantiate(None, delay_run, (1, operator.add, 2, 3), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 5)
        self.stop_timer(1)
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 3)
        self.stop_timer(0.1)
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, delay_run, (1, operator.add, 2, 3), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertRaises(TimeoutError, future.result)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)

    def test_result_before_running(self):
        future = self.instantiate(0.1, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        delay_run(0.5, future._set_running_or_notify_cancel, sync=False)
        self.start_timer()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 3)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)

    def test_exception_immediate(self):
        data = os.urandom(1 << 20)
        future = self.instantiate(None, return_, (data,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        test_exception = Exception('test')
        future = self.instantiate(None, throw, (test_exception,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), type(test_exception))
        self.assertEqual(future.exception().args, test_exception.args)

    def test_exception_delay(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.stop_timer(0.1)
        future = self.instantiate(None, delay_run, (1, operator.add, 2, 3), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.stop_timer(1)
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.stop_timer(0.1)
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, delay_run, (1, operator.add, 2, 3), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), TimeoutError)
        self.assertFalse(future.exception().args)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)

    def test_exception_before_running(self):
        future = self.instantiate(0.1, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        delay_run(0.5, future._set_running_or_notify_cancel, sync=False)
        self.start_timer()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)

    def test_valid_add_done_callback(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0,), {})
        requires_callback = {future}
        future.add_done_callback(requires_callback.remove)
        self.assertIn(future, requires_callback)
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.assertFalse(requires_callback)
        requires_callback.add(future)
        future.add_done_callback(requires_callback.remove)
        self.assertFalse(requires_callback)

    def test_error_add_done_callback(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0,), {})
        requires_callback = [{future} for _ in range(10)]
        callbacks = [s.remove for s in requires_callback]
        error = Exception()
        callbacks.insert(5, functools.partial(throw, error))
        for fn in callbacks:
            future.add_done_callback(fn)
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as cm:
            future.exception()
        self.assertIs(cm.exception, error)
        self.assertFalse(any(requires_callback))

    def test_set_running_or_notify_cancel(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertFalse(future.running() or future.done())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.running())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.cancelled())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```